# "Divisors" vs "factors"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, divisibility

Is there a difference between *divisors* and *factors*? Are they the same or are there differences?

Example: Find the factors and divisors of 18.

What I have found is answers that contradict each other:

[Onlinemath4all:](https://www.onlinemath4all.com/difference-between-divisors-and-factors.html)
Factors don't include one and the number itself. So for the example that would be 2,3,6 and 9
Divisors do include them. So for the example that would be: 1,2,3,6,9 and 18

[Quora:](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-divisor-and-a-factor)
There is no difference between factors and divisors. So for the example 1,2,3,6,9 and 18 would all be divisors and factors.

Someone also replies there that a divisor can be any number (even with a non zero remainder). In that case 5 could also be a divisor of 18 (with a remainder).

Comment: I agree that, when calculating $18/5,$ $5$ is the divisor

Comment: Yes, but that is not the same as saying "5 is a divisor of 18"  (which in my book is a false statement). The point I think is that there is no universally agreed-upon definition and that you have to pay attention to the context: the same word ("divisor") has different meanings in these two contexts - and we have not even started to talk about divisor vs. factor :-)

Comment: It really depends on where you are (and what definitions your book uses). There's a difference between " a divisor of a division" (JW's interpretation) and "a divisor of an integer" (NickD). It is unfortunate that the same term is used in very similar setups.

Comment: Ok, so context is important. A "divisor of an integer" is different than a divisor in a division (dividend / divisor - quotient). 

I think that the same may hold for factors: a factor of an integer is different than a factor as part of a multiplication (factor * factor = product).

Leaves me one question, if I need to find the factors of let say 8 do i include 1 and 8? Or are just 2 and 4 the only factors?

Comment: $1$ and $8$ are factors of $8$, but they are not *non-trivial factors* of $8$

Comment: The entry [*Factor*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factor.html) at *Wolfram MathWorld* explains that the inconsistency in terminology you have come across has arisen from a difference in usage between that adopted in mathematical literature and that sometimes adopted in elementary education. I recomnend you read that entry, and the entries [*Divisor*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Divisor.html), [*Proper Divisor*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html) and [*Proper Factor*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperFactor.html) at *Wolfram MathWorld*.

Comment: The corresponding entries [*Factor*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Factor) and [*Divisor*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Factor), in the online *Encyclopedia of Mathematics*, and the entries *Divisor (of an integer or a polynomial)* and *Aliquot divisor* linked from them provide further confirmation that the entries in *Wolfram MathWorld* give an accurate description how these terms are used in mathematical literature.

Comment: Thanks @lonzaleggiera those entries are very helpful! The wolfram entries give a good explanation of the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comment of Lonza Leggiera and can be found in the following wolfram entries:

[Factor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factor.html)

[Divisor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Divisor.html)

[Proper divisor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html)

[Proper factor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperFactor.html)